# Delphi wrappers for getnameinfo and getaddrinfo

Tags: delphi, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to find Delphi wrappers for [getnameinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [getaddrinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) socket APIs. Does anybody know where to find them or has created them and would not mind to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are part of [Indy 10](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/Files/Indy10.DE.aspx): declared in `IdWship6` unit, they are already used by `TIdStackWindows` in `IdStackWindows` unit.

Comment: I've ended using JWA version (see my answer) because I'm not using Indy, but your answer was indispensable as it provided me with an example on how to use those two functions correctly.

Comment: You might take a look at Synapse's declaration [here](http://synalist.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synalist/trunk/sswin32.inc?revision=146&content-type=text%2Fplain).

Answer (score 3):

They are included in [JEDI Windows API](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/category/downloads/jwa-downloads/), unit `JwaWS2tcpip`.